# dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs How to get information about the authenticated user?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm using [Dialogflow Fulfillment Library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs)

Is it possible to obtain information on the end user who is using the service?

I saw that the documentation talk about the [the session](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/WebhookRequest#FIELDS.session)

How do I implement an end-user authentication with DialogFlow?

I would already be happy to know the email of those who use the service